# HTML and JS image caching on iOS

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, ios

I have an extremely annoying problem - hopefully someone can shed some light or at least tell me I have to live with it.

I've written a basic medical image viewer that can display a series of jpg images. As the user scrolls through (finger, mousewheel, arrow keys), the active image is updated and displayed. I preload the images into the browser cache to improve the smoothness of scrolling. On PC and Android, there is no flashing effect while the new images is displayed in the DOM - its perfectly smooth. On my iPad (iOS 9.3.3) there is a very noticeable stutter while scrolling through the stack of images - on both Chrome and Safari. After a while it gets better. Interestingly though, I have a first generation iPad and I don't have this problem on it. The image series that I pre-load generally contains about 50 images, roughly 30KB each in size.

I've tried various methods of pre-caching:

**Using a PHP loop to insert images into the DOM and setting visibility to hidden.**

```
 <img src='$url$imagearray[$i]' width='1' height='1' style='visibility:hidden;margin:0;padding:0;height:0px;' />
```

**Link preload**

```
<link href="$url$imagearray[$i]" rel="preload">
```

**Javascript/Jquery in various flavours**

```
var jsArray = ["<?php echo join("\", \"", $imagearray); ?>"];
function preLoadSeries(arrayOfImages) {

    for (i = 0; i < arrayOfImages.length; i++) {
        images[i] = new Image();
        images[i].src = "<?php echo "$url"; ?>" + arrayOfImages[i];
            //console.log(images[i]);
    }
}
preLoadSeries(jsArray);
```

**EDIT:**
The images are added dynamically on user request, ie user clicks on download button, ajax fires server script to download and process jpgs on the Apache webserver and returns a View button to the same page. User clicks/taps button open the newly downloaded images on a new (image-viewer) page. If I open the images immediately, the scrolling is quite bad. If I wait a minute or two, it's much better. Does Apache have something to do with this, possible taking time to index newly added content? I need to reiterate that PC and Android is completely fine.

Thanks in advance